# What tools do you use for vulnerability scanning?

Tags: security, web-server

What are your favorite tools for checking for vulnerabilities in websites?

Answer (score 9):

I've used Nessus before.  It takes a bit to setup, but has a pretty comprehensive set of tests.

Comment: Nessus went commercial, there's OpenVAS instead.

Answer (score 4):

nmap is great for giving you the ports that are open and what is running on them

Answer (score 1):

- [HTTPrint](http://www.net-square.com/httprint/)
- Nessus (which, if installed on linux, typically has nmap as a port mapper)
- [Qualys](http://www.qualys.com/index.php)
- [MetaSploit](http://www.metasploit.com/)
- [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)
- [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

Answer (score 1):

WebInspect is pretty good, but pricey.  It takes a lot of handholding as well, not a lot of automated use.

Comment: Why the -1?  I'll take that you don't like it, but at least leave a comment!

Answer (score 0):

It's not free, but [McAfee Secure](http://www.mcafeesecure.com/us/) does an excellent job and provides very detailed reporting.

Answer (score 0):

[hping](http://www.hping.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Check insecure Dot Org... and web scanner
There are lots of great security tools there.
Some are open source, other are commercial.. 
nikto
praros proxy
web scarab
web inspect
burpsuit
whisker
wikto
acunetix wvs
watchfire appscan
n-Stealth

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a commercial web application security scanner.A list of WASS : http://www.webscanners.net/webscanners/index.html

Answer (score 0):

i prefer nessus as wonderful tool that is easy to use