# Firewall rules that will cause problems for nmap

Tags: security, firewall, iptables

**I'm not talking about just blocking ports.**

I remember finding a host that when I ran a normal tcp scan `nmap hostname`,  nmap wouldn't return any meaningful results.   It was having problems with timeouts.  If I set the timeout value to something pretty low and set `--max-retries 0` then it would work.

Does anyone know of a iptables rulesets that cause problems for nmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want prevent host from syn scan you can use 2 method:

1. Trap Method:

   iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport
   --dports 23,79 --tcp-flags ALL SYN -m limit --limit 3/m --limit-burst 6 -m recent --name blacklist --set -j DROP

   iptables -A INPUT -m recent --rcheck
   --nam blacklist -j DROP
2. Normal way:

   iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 7/s -m recent --name blacklist --set -j DROP

   iptables -A INPUT -m recent --rcheck --nam blacklist -j DROP

if you want prevent your Host from FIN, ACK, Xmas or other scan tell me update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. I don't remember the exact detail, but go look for a 'question' (actually, a Community Wiki) from me with the title "*iptables Tips & Tricks*". There, you can find an iptables rule specifically designed to stump nmap.

In addition, I deploy a `TARPIT` target in the `INPUT` chain. TARPIT basically 'traps' anyone trying to open a TCP connection by allowing the TCP three-way handshake, but afterwards locking the TCP Window Size to 0 and dropping all states regarding that connection in the firewall. The host that has tried to open a port is now trapped: connection is made, but it can't send anything, and since it never receives a FIN or a RST, it is stuck in TCP-Established state until TCP timeout*. Meanwhile, the firewall just chugs along merrily, since it has dropped all states of that connection, so no resource is being used.

A combination of both successfully stumped all kinds of portscanners. They die when they touch my firewall :)

* *TCP timeout is a* lot *longer than TCP SYN timeout. About three orders of magnitude longer, IIRC. Thus, portscanners will run* extremely *slowly as its threads get stuck waiting for TCP timeout.*

Comment: Here is the community wiki you mentioned: [iptables Tips & Tricks](http://serverfault.com/questions/245711/iptables-tips-tricks)

Answer (score 1):

you might find [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-detect-port-scan-attacks/) in teresting, it discribes how to detect and block portscans in realtime.