# iptables rule to drop SYN and FIN attacks

Tags: debian, iptables, nmap

From a Trustwave report, we are trying to set our server to block this type of request but after trying several combinations of rules, we can still see the ports.

Could anyone give me a hint or the set of necessary rules to block this request?

I'm using `nmap --scanflags SYN,FIN xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` to test if iptables is blocking or not.

Comment: This should be on by default, but just in case check you have syn cookies enabled with `sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies`.

Answer (score 3):

This rule will match if the syn flag is set

```
iptables -A BLOCK -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN,RST SYN -j DROP
```

And this one will match for the FIN flag

```
iptables -A BLOCK -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN,RST FIN -j DROP
```

note that you will need to tweak this as the syn rule will prevent incoming tcp connections at all for your device, perhaps set the specific port you want blocked?

Comment: Check some rules on this [post too](http://volc-hara.blogspot.com/2008/03/iptables-anti-scan-tricks.html).

Answer (score 2):

I use something to prevent this SYN attacks. Not sure if it is correct one for your case but you may take a look.
I count requests per second and block IPs with more than X (in my case 20) requests in 1 second. Works for me.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 20 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 1):

Go check my Community Wiki: [iptables Tips & Tricks](https://serverfault.com/questions/245711/iptables-tips-tricks)

Especially the following "answer": [Answer #245713](https://serverfault.com/questions/245711/iptables-tips-tricks/245713#245713)

Please note that for the blockage to be effective, it must be placed in **`-t raw -A PREROUTING`**

Answer (score 0):

There is a document entitled "Detecting and deceiving network scans" on the net, which goes into this with analytical detail, and finds the optimal blocking parameters.