# How to drop bogus tcp packets through iptables?

Tags: iptables, tcp

We are seeing the issue described here - http://archives.neohapsis.com/archives/bugtraq/2002-10/0266.html

In brief, we need to drop bogus packets, such as with SYN+FIN flags set. I can drop this particular packet by adding rule-

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -j DROP
```

Now there could be many more combination of flags. So should I add all of them or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Must be missing something from the report. All this work to prevent os finger printing? Or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Please summarize the issue you're seeing, instead of referring us to a link to read about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best time to drop bogus packets is when the packets are not yet tracked, thus in the "raw" table. Or, to be really precise: `-t raw -A PREROUTING`

Check out the following Community Wiki: [iptables tips & tricks](https://serverfault.com/q/245711/15440) by yours truly. One of the 'answers' there already contains a set of rules to drop bogus packets.

Comment: I used the rules mentioned in community wiki link you provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I propose to drop all the INVALID packets if you use the connection tracking with :
`iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -m comment --comment "DROP INVALID" -j DROP`

You can see too :
`-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -m comment --comment "Bad TCP Packet" -j DROP
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -m comment --comment "Bad TCP Packet" -j DROP
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -m comment --comment "Bad TCP Packet" -j DROP
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -m comment --comment "Bad TCP Packet" -j DROP
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -m comment --comment "Bad TCP Packet" -j DROP
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -m comment --comment "Bad TCP Packet" -j DROP`

Comment: You mean `-A INPUT` right?

Do I also need to add other combinations like `--tcp-flags ALL FIN,URG,PSH`?

Comment: Dropping INVALID packets ought to be sufficient. Why all the extra rules?

Comment: @sudouser : You are right -A INPUT. My Firewall is using FORWARD. Bad copy/paste, sorry.

Comment: @Michael Hampton, my solution is to provide some well known combinations which are filtered to in INVALID. You can choose which you want !

Comment: I don't want any of them :)