# Ip Tables Port 443 not open?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, linux-networking

im kinda lost here with my Settings. 
I configure Iptables via a file. But the port 443 is not open, and i dont know why, because i drop nothing before the 443 rule. I know, that iptables matters my chain.

iptables -L -n output:

[image]

my file looks like:

filter

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

And much other rules related to the ports like FTP and everything works...
Please give me any clue about this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is this server hosted?

Comment: Its a root server. thank you for your comment :) i managed it myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iptables Tips & Tricks](http://serverfault.com/questions/245711/iptables-tips-tricks)

Answer (score 1):

i Just managed it myself.

I had to open the 443 port this way on the beginning of my 443 chain:

> -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

now it works.